# How to aggregate multiple hdf5 files into a one image

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I have several (up to few hundreds) hdf5 files, which contain the results of a parallel simulation: each compute node creates an independent hdf5 file to avoid any synchronization problems.

Is there any way to create an 'image' of all data in hdf5 files, such what, this 'image' would look like it has all data, but in reality, it will provide data from other files?

Here what I'm looking for:

```
   "data-node0.h5"
      spike/PopulationA -> pandas data frame columns=[0,3,6,9]
   "data-node1.h5"
      spike/PopulationA -> pandas data frame columns=[1,4,7,10]
   "data-node2.h5"
      spike/PopulationA -> pandas data frame columns=[2,5,8,11]
      spike/PopulationB -> pandas data frame columns=[0,1,2,3]

   "data.h5" = aggregate("data-node0.h5","data-node1.h5","data-node2.h5")
   "data.h5"
      spike/PopulationA -> pandas data frame columns=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
      spike/PopulationB -> pandas data frame columns=[0,1,2,3]
```

**Note** that file `data.h5` doesn't contain any data. It uses data from `data-nodeX.h5` files.

**Update** Data in hdf5 files are pandas data frames with time series. The column in each data frame is 1D numpy array recorded from an object in the model. A column identifier is a unique ID of an object in the model. The table index is the model time in ms.

Comment: While I do not know hdf5, can you show code that produces one pandas dataframe *image* file? And what do you mean *aggregate*? Did you mean *append* or *merge*?

Comment: @Parfait none of these. I don't know whether is it possible to create such _image_. Each data-nodeX file contains a set of recordings from some objects in my model. Column's number is ID of an object. Objects can be grouped in populations, so some of the nodes compute object from different populations. I want to create some 'virtual' data file, which looks like it contains all data, but it just accesses to another data file and provides data from there. Kind of collective image of all data.

Answer (score 1):

In version 1.10+, HDF5 added a virtual dataset feature that allows you to map data from multiple datasets into a top-level 'virtual' dataset, which stores no data itself.

The documentation is here:
https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/docNewFeatures/NewFeaturesVirtualDatasetDocs.html

The complication, of course, is that it looks like you are using PyTables via Pandas and not raw HDF5. PyTables is HDF5, but adds a layer of structure and semantics on top of HDF5's groups and datasets. In order to create a virtual dataset based on PyTables, you are going to have to dig around in the sub-structure of the PyTables HDF5 objects to set up the mapping. Also, any virtual dataset you create will be a regular HDF5 dataset and not a PyTables table. This is certainly doable given a basic knowledge of HDF5, though possibly more work than you hoped.

h5py (a much lower-level and more direct Python wrapper for HDF5) has support for the virtual dataset feature, btw, so you can still do everything in Python, just not via PyTables.

Comment: Thx! But this won't virtualize pandas data frames, right? It will be bunch of frames in virtual file, not a one coherent frame, if I understand correctly. If so, individual numpy arrays without framing through h5py is the best choice.

Comment: Yes. I think so. PyTables is great and has many handy features, but h5py is more flexible and can take advantage of more advanced HDF5 features. There is work afoot to make the two work together more seamlessly, but I'm not sure how far they have gotten with that.

Comment: Though I will say that the PyTables layout is pretty straightforward, if I remember correctly. If you poke around in it (try using the HDF5 command line tools like h5dump and h5ls) you might be able to use the virtual dataset feature to fake a fully functional PyTables data table.